# Assign variable value from a text file in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this sample text file contains the following line

```
group1,name1
group2,name2
group3,name3
```

How to pass the value of first string to $group variable and second string to $name variable so I can use it in loop in the following script?

```
get-content data.csv -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match "$group" } | Out-File $name.txt -encoding Utf8
```

Comment: What do you want to match it with

Comment: First string in every line of the text file. Eg group1, group2 etc

Comment: The title of your question seems unrelated to the contents of your question. Can you clarify your goal?

Comment: Updated title and question. Hopefully it's clear up the confusion.

Comment: This is unclear to me.. Why not simpy `Import-Csv -Path 'data.csv' -Header Group, Name | ForEach-Object { $group = $_.Group ; $name  = $_.Name; <# Do what needs to be done with these variabes #> }` ??

Comment: Thanks @Theo. That's what I'm looking for. I don't really have experience in Powershell but I don't think I can simply ask question here without showing what I've tried so far and hence the script happens.

Comment: You're right to ask questions AND show what you have tried already! In this case, it was a bit unclear to me what you were trying to achieve. Glad to have helped a bit. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$file = get-content data.csv
$group = @()
$name = @()
foreach($line in $file){
$line = $line -split ","
$group += $line[0]
$name += $line[1]
}
$name > name.txt 
$group > group.txt
# Use ">>" if name or group.txt already exist
```

This will take every line in the file and split it up using `,` as a delimiter then assign the first value into the `$group` array and the same with `$name`

**Tested with exact `csv` file, working powershell version 5.1.18362.752**

**Update**: If you want to pass the array line by line, you can use:

```
$file = get-content data.csv
$group = @()
$name = @()
foreach($line in $file){
$line = $line -split ","
$group += $line[0]
$name += $line[1]
}
for($i=0;$i -lt group.length;$i++){
$group[$i] >> group.txt
}
for($i=0;$i -lt name.length;$i++){
$name[$i] >> name.txt
}
```

With the added for loop, it passes the arrays line by line

Comment: Appreciate that. Do you have any idea how to iterate those arrays to my script?
It works if just printing to console using command such as Write-Output but if I'm using foreach or forloop to iterate it fails because it passing whole array. I need to pass the array line by line to this script get-content data.csv -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match "$group" } | Out-File $name.txt -encoding Utf8

Comment: `$line -split ","` will fail if any of the fields in the csv **contains** a comma..

Comment: @Theo How will it fail?

Comment: @NekoMusume Because if a field contains a comma, like `"Doe, John"`, splitting on comma will create two fields out of that, meaning the csv will not be valid anymore. This is why fields like that are quoted. `Import-Csv` can handle commas embedded in quotes and parses correctly.

Answer (score 1):

as it is a csv why not use import-csv instead of get-content?
furthermore, foreach is not necesary, you can filter with a simple `where-object`.

```
import-csv data.csv -delimiter "," -header group,name|where{$_.group -match "group1"}
```

Comment: group1 is just a placeholder. I want to replace it with variable of the value of first string in every line of the text file.